How accurate can this memory-scanning “place replicator” be?
Need a new home, but missing your last one? Step into this high-tech environment replication chamber, and you can have it back. With state of the art brain-scanning technology (perhaps even brain-stimulating too, should it need to subconsciously prompt or guide your thoughts for as much detail as possible), hooked up to supercomputer processing and AI analysis, this tech reads your memories of a certain past environment—usually one you know very well and intimately, and better one from your recent past than a long-ago childhood—and brings it to life.
Just one concern. Memories tend not to always prioritize massive amounts of detail, and you’re probably aware of how fuzzy they can be, especially recollections of physical “maps” like that. Even with the galaxy’s most advanced brain-interfacing tech and supercomputer processing to analyze and interpret it, how accurate could the output product possibly be?
For example, when reconstructing all your furniture and knickknacks and other possessions in your house, how likely is it that something will be missing and you’d only notice later? (Or will you never be aware of it if there is, since the whole thing is built on just what you remember/are aware of?) How deeply could this device be able to probe into your conscious or subconscious memory, and what limitations in output would there still be from that?
(For what it’s worth, if anyone has an alternate idea on how a device could “know” what someone’s past home or other environment looked like besides basing it on memory reading, feel free to suggest alternatives)

Given how ubiquitous cameras are now, and probably only going to get more so in the future, the obvious (and very likely far more accurate) alternative is to simply reconstruct it from the photo & video archives. Bonus: this is more or less within the reach of current tech, no need for nigh-magical brain scanning.

@Gene not a bad idea in and of itself, but a key concept for the story this tech would appear in is that it works for and is used by total outsiders to the setting/society it’s in, where their memory might be the only available “archive” of the location to be reconstructed. Hence why I specified it’s specifically memory-based as opposed to just recreating things from a general mass of information like looking through the setting’s internet equivalent or some other archive

(a) I removed the [tag:internal-consistency] tag. That tag has specific rules (which you didn't follow) for a specific purpose (that you don't have). (b) You're assuming how memory works. The process of storing memory is different from the process of recovering it. (c) This falls square in the middle of my how much wood can a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood? Answer: He would chuck all the wood that a woodchuck could chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood category. There is no objectively correct answer - there's only the answer you justify (or not) in your story. VTC:TSB

Memory can be as detailed as you want. This is your story. Voting to close as there is no possible right answer for such a hypothetical tech.

Alternatively, you can fill up the gaps with objects that were common in the given time and place. E.g. IKEAize the memory.
